# how to mixup 2 class in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here are two JavaScript classes written by others, I need to use both of them:

1. [filter.js](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator/blob/master/lib/filter.js)
2. [validator.js](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator/blob/master/lib/validator.js)

I need to mix them up into a single class - it could be Validator or Filter class, or some class I define but I have to do this after Validator Filter initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since validator constructor is empty already you could do:

```
Filter.prototype = new Validator();
Filter.prototype.constructor = Filter;

Filter.prototype.modify = ...

...
```

`...` means adding all the filter methods to filter prototype like you are doing in the filter file.

> But I need do this after Filter and Validator initialized

You could try something like this then:

```
    var a = new Validator(),
        b = new Filter(); //They are initialized

    var tmp = Filter.prototype,
        key;

    Filter.prototype = a;

    for( key in tmp ) {
    Filter.prototype[key] = tmp[key];
    }

    Filter.prototype.constructor = Filter;
```

`b` ( a `Filter` instance ) will now have all `Filter` and `Validator` methods

Comment: But I need do this after `Filter` and `Validator` initialized

Comment: can you please be more precise on what exactly you want, from what you are saying it looks like you want methods of both class in one class only after both have been initialized ie constructor of both have done calling....

Answer (score 1):

```
function mixin(dst, src) {
  for (var p in src) {
    if (src.hasOwnProperty(p)) { dst[p] = src[p]; }
  }
  return dst;
}

var mixedProto = mixin(mixin({}, Filter.prototype), Validator.prototype);

var f = new Filter(), v = new Validator();

var siameseTwins = mixin(mixin(Object.create(mixedProto), f), v);
```

In case you do not have Objct.create or are afraid of using ES5 (no point, everything already have it except old things), you can define Object.create as

```
function (proto) {
  function f () {}
  f.prototype = proto;
  return new f;
}
```

Comment: Of course things like getters, setters, ES5 property attributes and possibly lot of other fancy things doesn't work with this simplistic `mixin` function, you have to make it more complicated if you want that as well

Comment: Btw there is a small whoopsie: `dst.p = src.p;` is supposed to be `dst[p] = src[p];` but +1